# How to make sub view to be round corner as super view in iOS?

Tags: ios, view

I have set a view (light gray) to be round corner using:

```
layer.masksToBounds = false
layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

It works fine. But when a sub view (dark gray) was added, that subview is not round as its super view.
[image: Round View]
How to make sub view to be round corner as super view?

Answer (score 0):

Please set `masksToBounds` to `true` while adding your subviews,

```
subView.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: Try adding `clipToBounds = true`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `cornerRadius` to subview as well.

```
subview.layer.masksToBounds = false
subview.layer.cornerRadius = 10
```

**Update**

By using `UIBezierPath` we can add roundness to any corner we want.

```
subview.roundCorners([.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomRight], radius: 6)
```

Extension

```
extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Comment: If like that, the sub view will round all four corners. What I want is only the top right and left corners for sub view.

Comment: Please check the **update** for adding roundness to top corners of subview

Comment: That's good. It's one of the solutions. Let see if there's any way to make sub view corner depends on super view.